What does this statement about "Block" mean in the official documentation?

Initial values specified for x, y, ... are evaluated before x, y,... are cleared.

It's from the Details in The reference to Block. And I can't understand it.
When are the local variables cleared and what's the meaning of "initial values are evaluated"?
Could anyone give an example to illustrate it? Thanks a lot!

You have to read this together with the second bullet point:

When you execute a block, values assigned to x, y, … are cleared. When the execution of the block is finished, the original values of these symbols are restored.

Now look at the following example:
x = 3;
Block[{x = x}, Print[x]]
(* 3 *)

If symbols were cleared before the initial values were evaluated, then the output of the code would be x.
x = 3;
Block[{x = (Clear[x]; x)}, Print[x]]
(* x *)

